# MySQL/phpMyAdmin comments in stored procedures removed

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm facing a simple problem. I don't know, if it's a matter of MySQL or phpMyAdmin, but everytime I update a stored procedure with comments in it's definition, the comments are removed. I found many forums where it's discussed, but not solved. Anyone has a solution or an idea? MySQL 5.7.17 x64, phpMyAdmin 4.6.6, Windows 7 x64, Apache 2.4 VC14 x64.

Thanks a lot.

**Edit** - it happens only while importing sql file or through SQL textarea. The comments are preserved using the "pen tool"

Sample stored procedure to import:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_Test`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_Test`()
BEGIN
  -- this comment will be removed
  # this comment will be removed as well
  /* this comment too */

  SELECT 1;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Tried phpMyAdmin 4.7.0 - same problem...

The simpliest solution was to switch to a different application - Adminer ([www.adminer.org](http://www.adminer.org/en)), which consist of just one file, is extremely fast, does not do anything I don't want to, and can do everything phpMyAdmin can do as well. So long phpMyAdmin, never again.

Comment: Can you show the procedure?

Comment: Was the source of the procedure any helpful?

Comment: Can someone else confirm this behaviour, please? I am really desperate.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it (MySQL 5.7.17). The behavior looks very strange. Possible it is a bug.

Comment: What version of phpMyAdmin do you have?

Comment: I tested on dbForge Studio for MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now I definitely know, this is a bug of phpMyAdmin. I reported two bugs:

1. comments in stored procedures are removed during import and in SQL textarea
2. new lines after comments are removed during export, which causes destruction of the procedure's source code:

So, this:

```
-- comment
SELECT 1;
```

becomes this:

```
-- comment SELECT 1;
```

These are the links to the reported bugs and two patches they made:

1. https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11717
2. https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13139

The second one will be part of 4.7.1 release and the first one has not been reviewed yet (as of 4th March 2017, 9:25), but both the patches work.

Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is quite common and there's an easy solution for it.
You should place your comments inside the procedure body, i.e., what's between `BEGIN` and `END`. The rest of the code are instructions to create the procedure and are lost once you run them.

Syntax for comments is:

1. /* ..... */
2. -- content

   ```
   BEGIN
   /*Comments*/
   --Comments
   END
   ```

If this doesn't work, try this out:

Inside `PhpMyAdmin`, once you select the database relevant to you, click the `wp_comments` table on the left hand side.

This will bring up all the records associated with your comments. As you can see, each has a number of fields attached to it. If you scroll over to the right, you’ll see a field called `comment_approved` with values of either `1` or `0`

`Pending` comments have a value of 0 and those that have been approved are 1. So to delete all pending comments in WordPress, we merely have to specify records with a `comment_approved` value of `1` which stops it from deleting them.

Also check if there exists a query which clears the `wp_comments` table.

Comment: See my sample stored procedure. I always place comments inside begin/end. They are removed anyway during import or using SQL textarea.

Comment: @Zelda try this out

Comment: And one more thing - the syntax for dashed comment is "-- comment": two dashes followed by a space. Otherwise it's considered a syntax error.

Comment: @Zelda Hey buddy, I recently tried this out. Try putting the comments outside of BEGIN and END. Atleast lets confirm this is works or not.